# Add text to absolute position in every slide automatically IN ADDITION to theme footer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, header-footer

I know this *sounds* like a repeat question, but I'm pretty sure it's not.

I am trying to add text to an absolute position in *every* slide of the presentation, *in addition to* to content already provided by the theme I am using.

Right now, I have defined this command:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\addtext}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[yshift=1.5ex,anchor=south west] at (current page.south west)
        {\tiny My Added Text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

And then, in every slide I want to use it, I have to issue that command within the frame definition.  The thing is, I *want* it in every slide, and requiring the user to remember to put it there is prone to forgetfulness.

I have seen a ton of examples here on how to add text to the footer that replaces the theme, or how to create commands like the one I've shared above.  My question is, how do I either do something like that in every slide, or make that command a part of every slide automatically?  I've tried adding that command to the `frametitle` using `\addtobeamertheme`, but it doesn't go well.

Ideas?

Comment: May I ask why you didn't add it to the `footline` theme instead of `frametitle` theme? Also is the text content going to be different for each slide or same text for every slide?

Comment: Hm, that wasn't on purpose; it was really more out of ignorance. Would 'footline' work where 'frametitle' failed? That is, would it not mangle the actual theming at the bottom of the slides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add to the footer without taking up space. Just add a `picture` of 0 dimension. Alternatively you can use package `atbegshi`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \setlength\unitlength{1ex}%
  \begin{picture}(0,0) 
    \put(1,4.5){\makebox(0,0)[bl]{\tiny My Added Text}}%
  \end{picture}%
}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame with Added Text}
  Text
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The first option you provided worked perfectly!  Thanks so much!